# How to separate input values for each Textfield?

Tags: swiftui

I stored the user's input into a dictionary, but the variables name and amount seems to not be a separate value for each Textfield rows. I tried adding self. to name and amount, but that seemed to not do anything. How can I implement this?

```
@Binding var numPeople: Int
@State var dict: [String : Float] = [:]
@State var name: String = ""
@State var amount: Float = 0.00
.
.
.
ForEach(1...numPeople, id:\.self) { stack in
    HStack {
         TextField("Name", text: $name)
             .padding()
                        
         Text("Amount in $:")
                        
         TextField("", value: $amount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
             .keyboardType(.numberPad)
             .onReceive(Just(amount)) { _ in
                 dict[name] = amount
             }
             .padding()
     }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using the same variables `name` and `amount` for all rows that you iterate with `ForEach`. If you want to have each row with their own fields managed separately, you need to separate the views.

Here below, a very schematic example of how it works:

In the parent view, the `ForEach` will call a subview:

```
@Binding var numPeople: Int

// Make @State vars private
@State private var dict: [String : Float] = [:]

// Note that you don't use the variables name and amount here
.
.
.
ForEach(1...numPeople, id:\.self) { stack in

    // Pass the dictionary, it will be updated by the subview
    SubView(dict: $dict)
}
```

Create a subview that will separately manage each name/ amount:

```
struct SubView: View {
    
    @Binding var dict: [String : Float]

    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var amount: Float = 0.00

    var body: some View {
       HStack {
         TextField("Name", text: $name)
             .padding()
                        
         Text("Amount in $:")
                        
         TextField("", value: $amount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
             .keyboardType(.numberPad)

             // I don't know why you need this, if the amount is
             // updated in this view. Maybe you can just use
             // dict[name] = amount, dropping the .onReceive()...
             // ... but it depends on your code
             .onReceive(Just(amount)) { _ in
                 dict[name] = amount
             }
             .padding()
        }
    }

    private func whatToDoWithNameAndAmount() {
         // Do whatever else you need with these variables
    }
}
```